Lovers kill ex-husband but he wakes up while being buried and won't die
I watched a film about a woman and her lover that kill the woman's ex husband and they bury him in mud and heavy rain in the darkness, and he reaches out his arm and grabs the womans hair, and rips of her triangle earring, and they they hit him on the head with a rock and bury him again. Then the woman finds her missing earring in her house and it's like a scary thriller, I only watched 20 minutes of it in around 1989 and I would love to know the name of the film.
More info: They bury him in a mud puddle in the rain. I didn't see the dead person alive after they buried him, they just show the stress between the couple because they have scary indications that he is alive and watching over them, his presence is everywhere.

Your description perfectly matches the opening scene of Until Death from 1987, a loose adaptation of The Postman Always Rings Twice from Italy.

Linda (Gioia Scola) and her lover Carlo (David Brandon) committed a horrible crime: eight years ago they murdered the woman's husband, while she was pregnant with his son. They hid the corpse and since then they are running a small hotel near a popular fishing lake. One rainy night a drifter named Marco (Urbano Barberini) arrives to the hotel, but he seems to know too many details about Linda's dead husband.

You can see the relevant scene below, mainly around 1:45. They dump his body in a puddle in the rain, he wakes up and tears off her earring and they then hit his head with a rock and bury him (the missing earring also turns up later on):



